# Google OAuth authentication with Django getting AuthException from localhost

Tags: python, django, authentication

I was trying to test Google authentication from Django with social-auth-app-django library with Authorized domain in /etc/hosts file.

All other authentications works fine like Facebook, Github, Twitter etc.
One thing about logout; logging out from application will not log out from actual backend, can we log out from backend with Django?

Created a project and obtained credentials from Google API console and put it in settings.py as SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY and SECRET.

With Javascript, getting redirect_uri mismatch,

```
Request Details

redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/www.simplysmile.in?id=auth725330
response_type=permission id_token
scope=email profile openid
openid.realm=
client_id=101069722014-u09qsn0dtnj8km7kid0883si0up9015p.apps.googleusercontent.com
ss_domain=http://www.simplysmile.in
fetch_basic_profile=true
gsiwebsdk=2
```

[image: Java script error]

with the link `<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google' %}">Login with Google</a>` getting AuthException.

[image: Auth Exception]

Please help to find a solution or share a tutorial to get Google authentication work with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Got a following [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) to Gmail API it works fine for Django.